# Flex, any way to programmatically highlight a field in red the way the validators do?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3, adobe

I'm doing some programmatic validation of some field values in a form, is there any way in Actionscript to highlight the field in red the way the validators do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to set errorString property on programmatic validation error

```
<s:TextInput errorString="error string value" />
<mx:TextInput errorString="error string value" />
```

Comment: Good answer.  I assumed that asking for an AS3 solution meant it was an AS3 object.  However, if you are starting/using Flex, you do want to use the tools that Flex provides.  Can you expand your comment and show how to set this value within AS3 code, and not within the tag?

Comment: Thanks, I've just tested setting the errorString property when validation fails and it works nicely.  How do you clear the validation error however?  Setting errorString to null did not work.

Comment: The errorString has it's issues with a proper reset, the solution that must teams I've been apart of use an empty string ("") to clear it.

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(textField);
```

To highlight the background in AS3:

```
textField.background = true;
textField.backgroundColor = 0xFFF000;
```

To highlight the border in AS3:

```
textField.border = true;
textField.borderColor = 0xFFF000;
```

To turn it off, just set the appropriate boolean to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using glow filter:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:GlowFilter id="gf" color="#ff0000" alpha="1" blurX="5" blurY="5" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:TextInput id="ti" width="80%"/>
<s:ToggleButton id="btn" label="glow on/off" click="ti.filters = btn.selected?new Array(gf) : null;"/>
```